# Regex to find a word that is not followed by two more words inside brackets

Tags: regex

I am attempting to add a rule to code linting that would require all of my functions to have a input parameters type specified.
These are some different options I am able to compile:

```
function someName()
function someName(someParam)
function someName(someParam as int)
function someName(someParam = "" as int)
function someName(someParam = "")
function someName(someParam, otherParam)
function someName(someParam as int, otherParam)
function someName(someParam, otherParam as int)
function someName(someParam as int, otherParam as int)
```

But I want to match these as invalid:

```
function someName(someParam)
function someName(someParam = "")
function someName(someParam, otherParam)
function someName(someParam as int, otherParam)
function someName(someParam, otherParam as int)
```

So, I want all cases where any of input parameters not have `as <some text>` to be matched

In these examples, I can use:

```
function \w+\(.*Param(?! (= .*|)as \w+).*\)
```

but I cannot figure out how to make it work with any input parameter name

I am fine with multiple passes to match different invalid cases, as long as they do not match valid ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to find all valid matches:

```bash
function\s+\w+\((?:\s*\w+\s+as\s+\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+\s+as\s+\w+)*)?\s*\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fyT0Ee/1)

Any line not matching above regex will be considered an invalid match.

**RegEx Details:**

- `function\s+\w+`: Match `function` followed by name of the function
- `\(`: Match starting `(`
- `(?:`: Start *optional* non-capture group

  - `\s*\w+\s+as\s+\w+`: Match first parameter that must have associated type
  - `(?:\s*,\s*\w+\s+as\s+\w+)*`: Match comma followed by another parameter that must have associated type. Repeat this group 0 or more times to match all such parameters
- `)?`: End *optional* non-capture group
- `\s*`: optional whitespaces
- `\)`: Match closing `)`

---

If you only want to find invalid matches then use:

```bash
function\s+\w+\((?!(?:\s*\w+\s+(.*?)as\s+\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+\s+(.*?)as\s+\w+)*)?\s*\))
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/fyT0Ee/3)

Comment: I want only invalid stuff to be matched in my linting script. I do not know how would i make it work with valid matches

Comment: sure, check my updated answer and `demo 2`.

Comment: Thanks `function\s+\w+\((?!(?:\s*\w+\s+(.*?)as\s+\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+\s+(.*?)as\s+\w+)*)?\s*\))` works for my latest edits